# Access member method from async call

Tags: javascript, class, oop, anonymous-function

I am trying to access a method from my "class" from a method called asynchronously by the code.

Here is my reduced class:

```
function FileProcessor(file, callback) {    
    this.file = file;
    this.callback = callback;
}

FileProcessor.prototype.readerOnload = function(e) {
    this.callback(e.target.result);
};

FileProcessor.prototype.process = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = this.readerOnload;

    if (this.file.type == 'text/xml') {
        reader.readAsText(this.file);
    }
};
```

My cal to this.callback works from the constructor FileProcess, works from process(), but doesn't work from readerOnload. I get:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `readerOnLoad` function is called in a different context than you expect, and you end up with a `this` value which is not an instance of `FileProcessor`.

Try this:

```
reader.onload = this.readerOnload.bind(this);
```

Or, if you must support older browsers:

```
var self = this;
reader.onload = function(e) { self.readerOnLoad(e); };
```

Comment: You might want to omit the `readerOnload` thing completely and invoke `self.callback` right away.

Comment: As the OP pointed out this is stripped-down code, I preferred to keep the `readerOnLoad` call, as there may be additional functionality in the read code in there.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked very well !!!